# Cannot connect/deploy Visual Studio Xamarin on Bluestacks

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, bluestacks

I'm using `MSVS2015Pro` with `Xamarin`.

I also installed `BlueStacks` to get an `AVD`.

But for some reason the the `BlueStacks AVD` doesn't appear on the available devices list to `debug` with.

Check the following image:

[image]

**[EDIT]**

FYI: On the `Visual Studio` Output window I get the error (I didn't see before):

```
Emulator name lookup failed for emulator 'emulator-5554'
```

[image]

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I added another screenshot to my question (under `[EDIT]`) where you can see an error I'm getting (I didn't see it before): `Emulator name lookup failed for emulator 'emulator-5554'`. I still cannot connect to the `BlueStacks AVD`. Maybe that error can help somehow to solve this.

Answer (score 15):

How to connect Bluestacks (4) Android Emulator with **Visual Studio** (this case 2019):

**Step 1:**

Activate ADB-Settings in Bluestacks

[image]

**Step 2:**

In VS go to *Tools -> Android -> Android Adb Command Prompt...* and insert

**adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555**

**Done!**

You should now see the device, which is selected in the Bluestacks Advanced-Settings as Device-Profil
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had a Xamarin Studio Addin that I used to use for this, but you can manually use `adb` (Android Debug Bridge) to enable/disable the connection.

Get the ip and port number of the running Bluestack instance via, it is usually `127.0.0.1:5555`

```
adb devices
```

Once you have that, you can connect and disconnect from it.

#### Connect:

```
adb connect {ip:port}
```

#### Disconnect:

```
adb disconnect {ip:port}
```

Ref: [SushiHangover.BlueStacks.Addin](https://github.com/sushihangover/SushiHangover.BlueStacks.Addin)

Comment: Could you say me how to do this with Visual Studio 2015  Pro?. I used Genymotion and I didn't have to do anything, it was ready and go, but I wanna use BlueStacks.

Comment: I added another screenshot to my question (under `[EDIT]`) where you can see an error I'm getting (I didn't see it before): `Emulator name lookup failed for emulator 'emulator-5554'`. I still cannot connect to the `BlueStacks AVD`. Maybe that error can help somehow to solve this.

Comment: see my answer, if this is still relevant for you :)